# how to solve payment verification error in google error [OR-IEH-01]

Tags: payment, google-pay

I paid for my Google play console account with my old VISA card, but it did not have my name on it and I had to go to the bank to change my VISA card.
I wanted to add my new VISA card but I got the error "An unexpected error occurred. Please try again later. [OR-IEH-01]"
Also  unfortunately I entered the wrong bank account number for this account and as soon as I realized my mistake I removed the payment method.

But in return Google still wants me to verify the wrong bank account number and I don't have that account number in my profile any more.

One more thing is that the bank statement didn't verified for the correct bank account too.
Is there a special format for the bank statement that google accepts?

What about the wrong account that was deleted but still on the verification list?
and how can I add my new visa card?

Thanks

I've tried to upload the correct documents for my payment verification, but all the documents related to bank (visa, statement) rejected.